# getting App Installation Failed - a valid provisioning profile is not available

Tags: xcode8, provisioning-profile

I just upgraded to Xcode 8.

Started getting this error when i try to run my app on my iphone:
[image]

**Things i have verified**

1. My iphone is listed in the dev portal with the correct UDID
2. I have removed and re-added the provisioning profiles many times in xcode

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have automatic code signing activated? What's the log output of the Sign step (see Report Navigator for a specific build)? Does the Sign step use your correct Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile? If not, you need to open the project's General Tab and either

- activate Automatic Code Signing 
  (Check "Automatically Manage Signing")
- or configure the Development Team and Provisioning Profile yourself